# How to show that $G$ is of class two ?or how to show $x_1(G)=\Delta(G)+1$?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $H$ be a nonempty regular graph of odd order and let $G$ be a graph obtained from $H$ by deleting $\frac{1}{2}(\Delta( H)-1 )$ or  fewer edges. How to show that $G$ is of class two? a graph is of  class two when$x_1(G)=\Delta(G)+1$ and belong class one when$x_1(G)=\Delta(G)$ . that $x_1(G)$ is a minimum  colors  need to color the edge of graph ,such that adjacent edge have a different color. Or the smallest number of colors needed in a (proper ,meaning no two adjacent edges are assigned  the same color) edge coloring of $G$  is a chromatic index , or edge chromatic number or $x_1(G)$.

Thanks

Comment: It would be nice if you'll provide a definition of class two graphs.

Comment: A graph is class two when $x_1(G)=\Delta(G)+1$ and graph belong class one when $x_1(G)=\Delta(G)$ , that $x_1(G)$ is a minimum  colors need to color the edges of graph such that adjacent edge has different color.

Comment: I know every regular graph of odd order is of class two, so $H$ is of order two. I can't proof that $G$  is of class two??